# How I can set cpu and memory limit for a process in java?

Tags: java, tomcat

Hi
I want to make a website using java and tomcat server.
The website will set cpu and memory limit for each user for their all process on a server. For example for each user %3 cpu and 100mb memory limit.

How can I make it?
Thanks

Comment: You can give each user a memory limit by giving them their own tomcat process, but this will not limit the CPU usage.

Comment: Usually limiting CPU is an OS setting which correspond to applications. I think software on the OS just always uses as much processing power as it can. I have never heard of Java being able to restrict it's own usage. Look at your tomcat settings or OS settings would be my first guess.

Comment: I've been looking for this for like almost 2 years. I haven't found a good solution so far. I've even asked how to implement a JVM inside a JVM, but projects for that have been abandoned. So, I'll make your question favorite :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with one Tomcat process. You need to spawn multiple child processes, each with it's own (-Xmx100m OR OS-specific memory quota) AND OS-specific settings to control CPU quota.

Depending on how malicious your users may become, you may also restrict number of available file descriptors, port ranges, disk quota, etc. At the end it may worth it to place each user's process into a VM and/or jail.

Answer (score 0):

There is no mechanism available in Java for enforcing limits on threads resource usage.  The only way you can do this, is by getting the underlying operating system to do it which will most likely require you to spawn a separate JVM for each restriction, and it will not be portable across platforms.

Note that you can put a timeout limit on a function call (using Executor) and have most operations interrupted.  This might be good enough for you.  If you need more, you again need the operating system to step in.